# How to install lastfm plugin for c# in .net framework

Tags: c#, plugins, last.fm

still newbie on C#.
i never installed a plugin, on my .net framework but i would like to build an application communicating with lastfm webservices.

so i went in the [api lastfm page](http://www.last.fm/api/downloads?setlang=en) and i downloaded [the lastfm c# plugin here](https://code.google.com/p/lastfm-sharp/).
now i have one zip with the plugin inside.
i don't know how to install it before to include it in my new project.
how can i do?

thank you in advance

Comment: It's a DLL isn't it? Just add it as reference to your project, you don't have to install anything.

Comment: no it's not. i cannot tell you what's the plugin. if you can check it for me. i really thank you.

Comment: by the way, the Lastfm Unofficial C# library does not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the binaries and not the source then make sure to download the binaries [download](https://code.google.com/p/lastfm-sharp/downloads/detail?name=lastfm-sharp-0.1.10-bin.tar.gz&can=2&q=) - otherwise you will need to build the source yourself.

Extract the zip file and inside you will find a dll called lastfm-sharp. I recommend moving this to a lib directory in your project. Then you need to add a reference to to your project which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx).

Comment: i did it, i imported the lib as a new project in the solution, i converted from 2008 to 2010 vs version, i corrected some warnings due to conversion, i compiled it, it was created the dll, and i included the reference into my project. thanks.

Comment: FYI, if you have included the project in your solution you should add a reference to that project - not the dll.